# How do I position a button to the right of the page when its parent uses flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am building the top navigation of a page. To the left, I have a logo and directly beside it I have my primary navigation links. I have two buttons that I want to position all the way to the right of the page, but I can't figure out how to get them over there. When I am able to get the buttons to move at all, it's only about halfway through the page...which isn't correct.

The buttons should be all the way to the right, like on https://webflow.com/

Notes: I used flex center to vertically center my navigation items.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
.wrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
}
nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 80px;
  width: 1000px;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 24px 0 24px;
}
nav a {
  color: #353D49;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav a:hover {
  color: #247BFA;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <nav>
      <img src="img/logo.svg" />
      <ul class="navItems">
          <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Learn</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="actionButtons">
        <button class="primary">Request a demo</button>
      </div><!--actionButtons-->
    </nav>
  </div><!--wrap-->
```

Comment: The button looks like its on the right side of the page to me when running your code. Can you add some more information detailing exactly how the current outcome differs from your desired outcome? Adding a 1px red border somewhere for reference may help.

Comment: I want it to be all the way to the right side of the page. Currently, it just hangs out at the end of the list. Imagine the logo/nav links and the button layout of https://webflow.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.actionButtons {margin-left: auto}`

or

`nav {justify-content: space-between}`

cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You can position the element to the right of the flex parent using `margin-left: auto`. You can do the same for vertical positioning with `margin-top: auto`.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
.wrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
}
nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 80px;
  width: 1000px;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 24px 0 24px;
}
nav a {
  color: #353D49;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav a:hover {
  color: #247BFA;
}

nav .actionButtons {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <nav>
      <img src="img/logo.svg" />
      <ul class="navItems">
          <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Learn</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="actionButtons">
        <button class="primary">Request a demo</button>
      </div><!--actionButtons-->
    </nav>
  </div><!--wrap-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Great case for `margin-left: auto;` though I would create a separate class.  The goal is to make code reusable, so nesting it in your `nav` tag will make it unwieldy if you continue with this method throughout your project.

I created a separate class for `.align-right` and you can reuse this in other areas of your project , rather than being limited to `.nav` or applying it to all of your `.actionButtons`

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
.wrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
}
nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 80px;
  width: 1000px;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 24px 0 24px;
}
nav a {
  color: #353D49;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav a:hover {
  color: #247BFA;
}
.align-right {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <nav>
      <img src="img/logo.svg" />
      <ul class="navItems">
          <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Learn</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="actionButtons align-right">
        <button class="primary">Request a demo</button>
      </div><!--actionButtons-->
    </nav>
  </div><!--wrap-->
```